Need help implementing a 16x13bit ROM
I'm trying to build a tiny "hex font ROM" analogous to the ones embedded in for example the HP TIL311 and am pretty much unable to find useful parts.
Since it's for hexadecimal, I'd need 16 "addresses" (4 bit) and (if I want to use the exact same font as a TIL311 which has 7 line+6 corner segments) 13 bit words.
I'm not a silicon foundry nor millionaire and I'd really like to avoid nonsense like a CPLD/FPGA/microcontroller because it just feels so wasteful.
The required diode matrix is <100 "ones", so not too horrible, but of course also rather large in footprint, which is a problem since I'm rather space constrained on the board in question, so I guess ideally some tiny parallel [E[E]]PROM in e.g. BGA. 3V3 or 5V5 would be fine (bonus points if it doesn't matter).
I was also thinking something along a GAL, but all the nice still-in-production ATF22V10s I could find are quite giant compared to modern surface mount parts.

I think you are saying you want the middle rectangle circled in red found in this datasheet. This would mean parallel-out. Is that a requirement?

that would be what that datasheet calls that, yes, why? i mean i literally said above that i'm trying to "steal" HP's font there.

It's because it's parallel-out. That means you cannot use serial to parallel. Just want to be sure and clear about it.

i mean yeah like i said above i think? please ask if anything's unclear, i think tho that only Kuba below said anything about things not being parallel (as a downside of tinytapeout)?

essentially my problem with non-parallel-out is that now i'm clocking shit anyway, might as well just use a microcontroller with something like 256bytes of memory and an endless loop copying an array indexed from one port to another port and get it all in one chip again. i'm looking for a "lower level" solution than that because it feels wrong to need a "thing to actively run" just to decode 4bits.

It was unclear to me, given Kuba's answer and then thinking about what you may or may not accept. It never hurts to be sure, my opinion. If you are offended by dumb questions, I'm happy to disappear. But your last comment just above this one makes it very clear. So thanks.

nah not offended sorry if that sounded wrong, it wasn't a "dumb question" i just didn't understand that it even was one before you edited :'D

One more dumb question:  May I assume you've already excluded the idea of soldering a 40 gauge wire tiny-matrix? I've done it before. So it's a thing. To keep it small would require some effort and a binocular microscope.

the wire matrix won't be the issue, more the requirement for all those diodes to be physical packages. the "wires" would just be traces because yeah not gonna weave that by hand :P unless you're suggesting some smart kinda charlieplexing-abuse-the-fact-our-output-drives-diodes to get away with actual wires?

Yeah. I'm just recalling the time using a wire-bonder. No, I don't have a good idea off the top of my head. Maybe something will come to mind. Sounds like you want more than one. So Kuba's direction may be the way to go.

hmmm I think something like a 4-to-16 onehot decoder and literally just wiring each output "digit" bit to all its segments might work actually if the LEDs are helping out and potentially some additional diodes where required on segments?

That's where my mind was just heading, oddly enough. But I wasn't thinking of saying it because I was unsure of size requirements and a 4x16 has more pins than you want.

as long as i can find a decoder that's small enough... so definitely none of that .1in dip packaging that's so nice and widely available :D and a quick glance at mouser suggests that most of the SMD ones are also still quite large.

Yeah. A 74154 in BGA? ;)

if only they actually made those. imagine literally tiling your physical logic cells :D

Call up HP and persist until you find someone who can find a waffle pack with a bunch of those decoder dice for you. Probably sitting on a shelf somewhere in Penang or otherwhere.

Have you seen reTIL (a Hackaday project)?

honestly kinda surprised given they make WS2812 drivers without LEDs and there's even a 74xxx rom containing a Teletext font for TVs but nobody thought that "hex to 13 segment" was something that people might wanna do with custom leds?

@AndrewMorton yes, that's one of the various remakes using a microcontroller, which i'm trying to figure out how to avoid.

@nonchip Used to have fusible roms. But not in the shape you want. More like 8 bit address, 4 bits out. (1024 bits as in the MMI 5300, for example.) The old square loop toroid cores, towards the end of the core memory business cycle, had an outside diameter of far less than 1 mm (3 of them could sit side by side in a triangle, inside a circle of 0.5 mm diameter. So a core memory could get there. Perhaps a new business venture here? ;)

@AndrewMorton Thanks for that link. That's REALLY impressive work. It used to require a wire bonder and custom IC for that kind of miniaturization. And it's not even the smallest LEDs (though it is the smallest cheap LEDs).

Once upon a time we'd have used PALs but I believe they don't make them any more.  Do we consider SLG46620 as wasteful?  I'm also looking at the gate circuit of 7447 waiting for a good idea to arrive.  :-)

@jonathanjo see above for GALs (which are essentially "EE PALs"), while they still make them, they make them at the same package size as in ye olden days, so giant compared to the modern alternative. and yeah the greenpak is a bit strange to judge, on one hand it's probably smaller than most CPLDs one could get in a useful package, but on the other hand it's still way more wasteful than eg the STM8 used in the reTIL (which also sounds way easier tooling-wise than the proprietary magic from greenpak). so yeah if you know a 22V10 in a modern  chipscale package size, i'll take a thousand :D

... or Atmel 16v8, available in PLCC 10mm square.
.

that one wouldn't have enough output pins, and is just 1.5mm smaller than the 22v10. we're talking about a situation of "silicon vs plastic size", not just "square vs stick-with-pins" sadly.

i'm starting to suspect my "best" option (apart from the obvious of giving up and using a mcu) would be some chipscale array package of lots of individual mosfets or whathaveya and then just do open collector wired-or.

Using a tiny MCU would be the simplest and cheapest solution, in my opinion. Use Charlieplexing to minimize pin count.

I take it you're not looking to make enough of them to be able to buy bare die ATF22V10s? It's an idea...

Are you sure you don't want to use an FPGA? The Lattice MachXO3 or MachXO2 series might suit your needs pretty well; it's flash-based, so it doesn't need to read in configuration data on boot, and they come in pretty tiny packages; you can get some in 3 mm square with 30+ i/o pins. You don't even need a clock, since this is all combinational logic and there's no need to read in the configuration from external memory.

@Hearth yes i am -_-

Excellent question!
The ROM is small enough to have several fonts and get it done with TinyTapeout and you get a custom IC! That’s on a hobbyist budget. It will need an external parallel-to-serial and serial-to-parallel shift register due to pin count limitations. But those can be had in tiny packages, so not a big deal.
You should have enough time (2 months from now) to get your design into TinyTapeout TT08 run.
Efabless/chipignite + a group buy will do the trick to get a full-pin out solution. I’m sure there’d be plenty of people who’d like to get their hands on some. The chip would need both the ROM and drivers for the LEDs. That way it’d be easy to use.

problem there is the tinytapeout package is about as large as a ATF22V10 DIP and at that point we're just wasting 99.99% of it anyway ontop of requiring an externally clocked fetch-execute circuit, so might as well go for any microcontroller ruled out as wasteful at that point. and like i said, i am looking for a part to implement this in, not to spin my own silicon.

and chipignite is just trying to sell me a masked FPGA/uC, if i'm not misunderstanding their "caravel SoC"?

@nonchip Efabless is full custom digital no need for a SoC. It’s an FPGA to ASIC service, with more open tools. SoC is an option they offer IIRC.

Consider a Silego (Renesas) GreenPAK device. These are small-footprint "programmable FPGAs" that could easily implement a 16x13 LUT.
GreenPAKs have an array of lookup tables of various sizes that can be connected together to form larger ones as needed.
Example of an LED driver: https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/apn/1097-7-segment-led-control-greenpak
They're tiny, easily small enough to be tucked under a typical hex display.
